# How to escape a space in a path on msys2?

Tags: msys2

I want to invoke `C:\Program Files (x86)\Leela\Leela0100.exe` and pass it a filename:

```
#!/bin/bash -x

BASE="c:/Users/supreme"
DROPBOX="$BASE/Dropbox"

DOWNLOADS="$BASE/Downloads"

cd $DOWNLOADS
SGF=`ls -th *.sgf | head -1`

GAMES="$DROPBOX/Baduk/Games"

mv $SGF $GAMES

LEELA='c://Program Files (x86)//Leela//Leela0100.exe'

cd $GAMES
$LEELA $SGF
```

However, invoking my script via `bash -x toleela.sh` under MSYS2 yields the error:

```
c:\Users\supreme\Dropbox\Programming>bash -x toleela.sh 
bash -x toleela.sh 
+ BASE=c:/Users/supreme
+ DROPBOX=c:/Users/supreme/Dropbox
+ DOWNLOADS=c:/Users/supreme/Downloads
+ cd c:/Users/supreme/Downloads
++ ls -th '9001447-269-Winggo-princepawn (1).sgf' 9429961-080-princepawn-RyanBLee.sgf
++ head -1
+ SGF=9429961-080-princepawn-RyanBLee.sgf
+ GAMES=c:/Users/supreme/Dropbox/Baduk/Games
+ mv 9429961-080-princepawn-RyanBLee.sgf c:/Users/supreme/Dropbox/Baduk/Games
+ LEELA='c://Program Files (x86)//Leela//Leela0100.exe'
+ cd c:/Users/supreme/Dropbox/Baduk/Games
+ c://Program Files '(x86)//Leela//Leela0100.exe' 9429961-080-princepawn-RyanBLee.sgf
toleela.sh: line 18: c://Program: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As was already pointed out to you on IRC, you are missing quotes around the variable expansions on the last line of your script (also on other lines).

```
"$LEELA" "$SGF"
```

The double forward slashes (`//`) in your executable path are not right. Use single forward slash (`/`) <strike>or a double backslash (`\\`)</strike> instead. EDIT: Backslashes are more complicated, so stick to forward ones.

Comment: [single forward slash works](https://gist.github.com/metaperl/d8fe4887d202cd8b2c04709049b9e0de)